# How to Set Password on Elastic Search (V:6.5.4)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to set a password on elastic search version-6.5.4 but an error occurs like "setup-passwords is deprecated". It has a solution for version- 6.1.1 which is not working for version-6.5.4 `enter code here`Can you help me with it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hello could you try `elasticsearch-setup-passwords` as a command. It has been renamed ( see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-passwords.html) and [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/password-set-up-is-deprecated/141219))